# Example of non reflexive Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, duality-theorems

I searched online but did not find any example of non-reflexive Banach space.
Can you give me some examples of non-reflexive Banach space?

Comment: $L^1$ is the standard example.

Comment: $C[0,1]$. ${}{}{}$

Comment: The simplest example is probably  $c_0$ because you can explicitely calculate the bidual  $c_0''=\ell\infty $.